# Does overriding OnNcPaint() affect the painting of the client area of a window?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, onncpaint

I want to change the appearance of a window's caption bar, so I decided to override the `OnNcPaint()` method of `CMainFrame`. But when I did this, I found a problem. If there is another window covering my window, and I drag the window quickly, the content of the client area of my window disappeared, which came to sight only when I stopped the dragging.

My overridden `OnNcPaint()` is like below:

```
void CMainFrame::OnNcPaint()
{
    CDC* pWinDC = GetWindowDC();
    //do some drawing
    ReleaseDC(pWinDC);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my approach? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Unless you use a clipping region set up to exclude the client area, you *can* paint over it from `OnNcPaint()`. So... if your drawing logic can't be modified to exclude the client in some other way, set up an appropriate clipping region first:

```
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
CRect rectClient;
GetClientRect(&rectClient);
rectClient.OffsetRect(-rect.left, -rect.top);
rect.OffsetRect(-rect.left, -rect.top);
pWinDC->ExcludeClipRect(&rectClient);
// ...
// draw stuff here
// ...
pWinDC->SelectClipRgn(NULL);
```

Comment: The client rect does not include things like the scrollbars, so this will allow ncpaint to draw over them.  Just FYI.

Comment: offsetting the rectangle rect after the rectClient is redundant.